# Ограничение длины регулярного выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть регулярное выражение

```
/^[A-Za-z]+[\d\.\+a-zA-Z]*@+[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$|^[\d\.\+a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-z]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/
```

Мне нужно чтоб сумма всех символов не превышала 60. Проверку на это нужно сделать именно в регулярном выражении. (?=.{5,60}) почему то не работает. 
Пишу на Javascript.

Вот пока что получается:

```
  function validateEmail(email) {
  return console.log(
    /^(?=.{5,60})([A-Za-z]+[\d\.\+a-zA-Z]*@+[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$|^[\d\.\+a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-z]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$)/.test(email));
}
validateEmail("email@gmail.com");
```

Задача стоит таким образом:
Напишите регулярное выражение для валидации email, которое будет проверять строку на соблюдение данной структуры: не менее одной буквы латиницей, любое количество цифр, возможна точка и символ + , затем символ @ , далее не менее одной буквы латиницей, потом точка и не менее одной буквы латиницей, сумма всех символов не должна превышать 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что при ограничении по минимуму позитивное lookahead работает, как вы предполагаете, а при ограничении по максимуму — нет, потому что оно проверяет количество символов, но не проверяет, чтобы это количество было максимальным (если символов 61, оно всё равно срабатывает, потому что внутри этих 61 есть необходимые 60). Можно соединить положительное lookahead для минимума и отрицательное для максимума:

```js
/^(?=.{5})(?!.{61})([A-Za-z]+[\d\.\+a-zA-Z]*@+[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$|^[\d\.\+a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-z]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$)/
```

Или добавить в проверку границы:

```js
/^(?=^.{5,60}$)([A-Za-z]+[\d\.\+a-zA-Z]*@+[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$|^[\d\.\+a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-z]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$)/
```

Кстати, если я правильно понимаю, проверка на минимум здесь избыточна, потому что у нас и так есть 5 обязательных символов: буква-собака-буква-точка-буква.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробное объяснение. Все работает, очень помогли!